# More imitation of Enumerable in VBA

Tags: algorithm, vba, collections

I was inspired by [Me How's question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59215/basic-imitation-of-c-enumerable-in-vba-or-any-other-static-class/59237#59237) to see how far I could push an imitation of [.Net's Enumerable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx).

The new functions can obviously handle Collections, but can also handle any collection-type object whose items have a default value. If a `collectionObject`'s items don't have a default value, Runtime Error 438 "Object does not support property or method" is raised. So, things like `Cells` and `Range` work, but `Worksheets` doesn't.

`Min` and `Max` only differ by one operator, so there's some duplication there, but I don't know how to refactor it out. `Intersect` also seems inefficient to me, but I couldn't imagine a better algorithm. So, those are particular areas of interest to me. Suggestions for which features to add next would also be appreciated.

#### Enumerable.cls

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Enumerable"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Private c As Collection ' used for Range

Public Function Range(ByVal startValue As Long, ByVal endValue As Long) As Collection
Attribute Range.VB_Description = "Returns a collection of longs."
    Set c = New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = startValue To endValue
        c.Add i
    Next
    Set Range = c
End Function

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = c.[_NewEnum]
End Property

' All of these functions work only on collectionObjects whose items have a default value.
' If the items do not have a default value,
'   Runtime Error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method" is raised.

Public Function Contains(collectionObject As Variant, itemToSearchFor As Variant) As Boolean
Attribute Contains.VB_Description = "Checks if an item exists in a Collection. Matches on the default property."
    Dim item As Variant
    
    For Each item In collectionObject
        If item = itemToSearchFor Then
            Contains = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
    
    Contains = False
End Function

Public Function Min(collectionObject As Variant) As Variant
Attribute Min.VB_Description = "Returns the item with the minimum value in a Collection. Uses the default property."
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim isFirstTry As Boolean: isFirstTry = True
    
    For Each item In collectionObject
        If isFirstTry Then
            result = item
            isFirstTry = False
        Else
            If item < result Then
                result = item
            End If
        End If
    Next item
    
    Min = result
End Function

Public Function Max(collectionObject As Variant) As Variant
Attribute Max.VB_Description = "Returns the item with the minimum value in a Collection. Uses the default property."
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim isFirstTry As Boolean: isFirstTry = True
    
    For Each item In collectionObject
        If isFirstTry Then
            result = item
            isFirstTry = False
        Else
            If item > result Then
                result = item
            End If
        End If
    Next item
    
    Max = result
End Function

Public Function Intersect(collection1 As Variant, collection2 As Variant) As Collection
Attribute Intersect.VB_Description = "Returns a new collection containing the items that are common to both collection parameters. Returns Nothing if either parameter IsNothing."

    If collection1 Is Nothing Or collection2 Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set Intersect = New Collection
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim innerItem As Variant
    
    For Each item In collection1
        For Each innerItem In collection2
            If item = innerItem And Not IsEmpty(item) Then
                Intersect.Add innerItem
            End If
        Next innerItem
    Next item
End Function
```

For anyone interested, the reason you can call these functions without creating a new instance is [setting `VB_PredeclaredID = True` creates a default instance of the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199159.aspx).

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/204509/Functors-in-VBA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a potential problem with your `Intersect` method. It only works as expected when there are no repeated items in either collection. I'm not sure what the desired behavior is, but if you have 3 copies in `collection1` and 2 copies in `collection2` then the returned collection has 6 copies. Now I know that in most cases Intersect only makes sense with sets, that is, one of each item, so this may not be relevant.

Comment: Collections can have duplicate items, so this is indeed a bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like that you're relying on default properties, especially in the `Contains` method: **in many cases your Contains method will return false positives for objects**.

Simply because an object has value XYZ for its default property doesn't mean another object with value XYZ can be considered equal - in fact, with your code **two objects of different types could be considered equal** under some unfortunate circumstances.

Fortunately that's an easily avoidable bug.

A collection of objects will hold a bunch of *references* - to know if a given object exists in a collection you can iterate the collection and if you find that reference, you can safely return `True` and be confident that the specified object *does* exist in the collection.

But before you can check for a reference, you need to be sure you're dealing with an `Object` reference, because `ObjPtr(1234)` (or any other non-object value) will raise a "Type Mismatch" runtime error.

[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) gives us the `IsObject` function to do that. Hence, first thing I'd do is try to know whether I'm dealing with an object or not.

This splits the function in two distinct parts: the `Else` block can deal with what I like referring to as *value types* - basically anything that's not an `Object`. Your code works well in these cases:

```
Public Function Contains(collectionObject As Variant, itemToSearchFor As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In collectionObject

        If IsObject(item) Then

        Else

            If item = itemToSearchFor Then
                Contains = True
                Exit Function
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

What you're trying to do here, is to perform an *equality comparison*. When `item` is an `Object` the only way to reliably determine if the `itemToSearchFor` *is the same object* as your `item`, is to compare their references:

```
If ObjPtr(item) = ObjPtr(itemToSearchFor) Then
    Contains = True
    Exit Function
End If
```

Bottom line: don't mix apples and oranges - a `Variant` can be anything, and since a `Collection` can be a bunch of totally unrelated things of various types, you have no choice but to evaluate `IsObject` for each `item`.

---

Here's how I had implemented `Contains` in [my `List<T>` implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/32618/23788):

```
Public Function Contains(value As Variant) As Boolean
'Determines whether an element is in the List.

    Contains = (IndexOf(value) <> -1)

End Function
```

Well ...yeah, so here's how I had implemented `IndexOf` in that class:

```
Public Function IndexOf(value As Variant) As Long
'Searches for the specified object and returns the 1-based index of the first occurrence within the entire List.

    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim isRef As Boolean
    isRef = IsReferenceType

    Dim i As Long

    If Count = 0 Then IndexOf = -1: Exit Function
    For i = 1 To Count

        If isRef Then

            found = EquateReferenceTypes(value, item(i))

        Else

            found = EquateValueTypes(value, item(i))

        End If

        If found Then IndexOf = i: Exit Function

    Next

    IndexOf = -1

End Function
```

Where `IsReferenceType` calls `IsObject` on the first item - in that case I could safely only check the first item in the list, because that collection could only ever have items of a single type, so if the first item was an object, they're all objects.

For completeness, the interesting part:

```
Private Function EquateValueTypes(value As Variant, other As Variant) As Boolean

    EquateValueTypes = (value = other)

End Function

Private Function EquateReferenceTypes(value As Variant, other As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim equatable As IEquatable
    If IsEquatable Then

        Set equatable = value
        EquateReferenceTypes = equatable.Equals(other)

    Else

        'object doesn't implement IEquatable - use reference equality:
        EquateReferenceTypes = (ObjPtr(value) = ObjPtr(other))

    End If

End Function
```

Custom classes could implement a simple `IEquatable` interface if reference equality wasn't desirable:

```
Public Function Equals(ByVal other As Variant) As Boolean
'return True if [other] can be considered equal to this instance.
End Function
```

And [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) has a `TypeOf` keyword that can be used for checking types, so you could have a little function like this, to call before attempting a "type cast":

```
Private Function IsEquatable() As Boolean
    If IsReferenceType Then
        IsEquatable = TypeOf First Is IEquatable
    End If
End Function
```

(again, that one only checks the first item in the `List` - it's just food for thought ;)

Comment: You've got a really good point about object equality, but does `ObjPtr` offer any advantage over the [Is Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242809(v=vs.60).aspx)? `Is` seems much less verbose.

Comment: Not really, `Is` looks like a shorthand for `ObjPtr` comparisons. It's just, like the `=` operator, it has too many meanings to my taste - notice its semantics are different in `TypeOf x Is ISomeInterface`.

Answer (score 4):

I explained in another answer my concerns about how your implementation of `Contains` deals with object variables, and that had to do with what's considered *equal* when talking about objects.

For `Min` and `Max`, it's not about *equality* - it's about *comparability*. Comparing objects by their default property value actually makes sense.

When objects don't have a default property, you're basically stumped here - you're left with no reliable way of *comparing* two objects. The .net framework solved that with the `IComparable` interface, which is pretty easy to imitate in VBA:

```
Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Variant) As Integer
'return  1 if [other] is greater than this instance;
'return -1 if [other] is smaller than this instance;
'return  0 if [other] is equivalent to this instance.
End Function
```

Similar to the `EquateReferenceTypes` function in my other answer, this would fit the bill here:

```
Private Function CompareReferenceTypes(value As Variant, other As Variant) As Integer

    Dim comparable As IComparable

    If IsComparable Then

        Set comparable = value
        CompareReferenceTypes = comparable.CompareTo(other)

    Else

        'try to compare default property values, or let it blow up!

    End If

End Function
```

And then you can write custom classes that implement `IComparable` to specify *how* instances should be compared to each others.

---

Looking at your `Min` implementation, I'd get rid of the `isFirstTry` Boolean, and replace it with a `IsEmpty(result)` check within the loop:

```
For Each item In collectionObject

    If IsEmpty(result) Then result = item
```

---

I really, really like this `Enumerable` "static" class. So much I'm seriously considering moving a lot of the `List` logic into that `Enumerable` class. With `IEquatable` and `IComparable` interfaces in the mix, I find it adds quite a bit of useful tooling to the language.