# Sorting a collection

Tags: sorting, vba, collections

Related to, but not exactly a follow up of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59595/more-imitation-of-enumerable-in-vba). After fixing some issues discovered in the last review, I added a little more functionality to the `Enumerable` class. The problem is, I've never sorted before. I tried (and failed)to implement a few of the standard algorithms before coming up with this. It's not very efficient. It has to check to see if the collection `IsSorted` and just keeps looping until it is.

- Is there a way to make this more efficient without using a more advanced algorithm?
- What would be a simple to understand algorithm that is more efficient than this?

I realize that I could simplify some logic if I created some interfaces, but I would like to work with "built in" collections without wrapping everything in a class that implements an interface.

Bonus points to anyone who can tell me what algorithm I ended up using. I just kept testing until it worked.

```
Public Function Sort(collectionObject As Collection) As Collection

    Dim item As Variant
    Dim innerItem As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim index As Long

    Do Until IsSorted(collectionObject)
        For i = 1 To collectionObject.Count
            index = i

            If IsObject(collectionObject(i)) Then
                Set item = collectionObject(i)
            Else
                item = collectionObject(i)
            End If

            For j = i To collectionObject.Count
                If IsObject(collectionObject(j)) Then
                    Set innerItem = collectionObject(j)
                Else
                    innerItem = collectionObject(j)
                End If

                If item > innerItem Then
                    collectionObject.Add item, After:=j
                    collectionObject.Remove index
                    index = j
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Loop
End Function

Private Function IsSorted(collectionObject As Collection) As Boolean

    Dim item As Variant
    Dim previous As Variant

    For Each item In collectionObject
        If item < previous Then
            IsSorted = False
            Exit Function
        End If

        If IsObject(item) Then
            Set previous = item
        Else
            previous = item
        End If
    Next item

    IsSorted = True
End Function
```

Comment: You can't define the `>` or `<` operators operators for any custom class in VBA, nor can I think of any objects where those operators are already defined.  If that is true then whenever `IsObject` is true you will get a error when comparing the objects.

Comment: Not exactly true @ptwales. It will throw runtime error 438 "Object does not support method" only if the object does not have a Default Property.

Comment: @ptwales maybe you could mention in an answer that I should handle that error and raise a better one *nudge nudge*.

Comment: _patience, young grasshopper_

Comment: Seems like I am late for the party but hey - [why not implement an imitation of IComparer along with sorting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881863/how-to-use-comparison-methods-between-class-object-modules-in-vba-in-a-similar-m/19908375#19908375)

Comment: You can then [pass one of the objects properties (or by its type) as the parameter criteria for sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489594/data-structure-which-needs-to-be-filled-in-vba)

Comment: I'm heading that direction I think. Thanks for the example @mehow. That should save my forehead from some keyboard indentations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## FEAR

This is a red flag.

```
Do Until IsSorted(collectionObject)

    ' Sorting algorithm 

Loop
```

Your algorithm should return a sorted sequence and should not need to be checked.  If it fails the check you should rewrite your sorting algorithm and not simply try to do it again.

### Abstracting Methods

This bit of code is used often enough to merit it's own sub routine

```
Sub AssignUnknown(ByRef dest As Variant, ByRef src As Variant)

    If IsObject(src) Then
        Set dest = src

    Else
        dest = src

    End If

End Sub
```

Now your code looks so much better!  It looks like a bubble sort but

```
For i = 1 To collectionObject.count
    index = i

    AssignUnknown item, collectionObject(i)

    For j = i To collectionObject.count

        AssignUnknown innerItem, collectionObject(j)

        If item > innerItem Then

            collectionObject.Add item, After:=j
            collectionObject.Remove index
            index = j

        End If

    Next j

Next i
```

### Algorithm

it doesn't work, hence you needing to loop until it is sorted.  You are only a few steps away from true bubble sort though, which is IMO simpler.

```
    For i = collectionObject.count To 2 Step -1

        ' hasSwapped = False

        For j = 1 To i - 1

            If collectionObject(j) > collectionObject(j + 1) Then

                collectionObject.Add collectionObject(j), After:=j + 1
                collectionObject.Remove j
                ' hasSwapped = true

            End If

        Next j

        ' If Not hasSwapped Then goto sorted ' Exit For

    Next i

sorted:
```

In short, instead of bubbling up the same object each time, the BubbleSort drops the current item for the next one when it finds a larger item.  This means after each inner loop the item at position **i** is in the correct place, which is why the outer loop is counting down not up.

**hasSwapped** uncommented allows for early exit if the sequence is already sorted.  For more information on the bubble sort, wikipedia has a great article.  I also found [this site with some cool animations](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/bubble-sort) while trying to figure out your sorting algo.

Also note that **AssignUnknown** is no longer needed.

### Error Handling

As we discussed in the comments, the comparison operators will not be defined for objects that do not have a default property.  It can't be fixed, but we can raise a more descriptive error

```
    On Error Goto no_default_property

    ' bubble sort

sorted:
Exit Function
no_default_property:

    If Err.Number = 438 Then ' preferably use the vb constant that I don't know
        Err.Clear
        Err.Raise 438, "Sort", "An item in the collection does not have a default property"

    End If

End Function
```

### After Thoughts

Consider writing **CollectionToArray** and **ArrayToCollection** functions so you don't need to duplicate sorting methods for Collections and Arrays.  Also consider a *Sorted* function that returns a sorted copy.

```
Sub Sorted(collec As Collection) As Collection

    Set Sorted = collec 
    Sort Sorted

End Sub
```

I was tempted to insist you use a **Swap** function like this.

```
Sub Swap(ByRef a As Variant, ByRef b As Variant)

    Dim t as Variant
    t = a
    a = b
    b = t

End Sub
```

However, you are supporting objects in your collection, you will need to make that routine `SwapUnknown` that uses **AssignUnknown**.  You could avoid calling `IsObject(a)` twice but I prefer the simpler solution.

```
Sub SwapUnkown(ByRef a As Variant, ByRef b As Variant)

    Dim t as Variant
    AssignUnknown t, a
    AssignUnknown a, b
    AssignUnknown b, t

End Sub
```

I didn't include this because:

- Your current swap method could be faster depending on how `Collection` is implemented
- Abstracting your current method seems pointless.
- It doesn't require **AssignUnkown**, which cuts out some ugly code.

Answer (score 5):

- You should use a `Sub` instead of a `Function` as you don't return anything.
- Your inner loop

  ```
  For j = i To collectionObject.Count
  ```

  should start at `j = i + 1`
- As the `Count` property of the collectionObject is accessed often, you should introduce a new variable to store the value once.
- A null check for the passed parameter should be added.

**Logic**

Looking only at the `Sort` method the collection is not sorted when `item > innerItem` evaluates to true. So let us introduce a `Boolean` which will save this state and let us change the Loop from a Do Until()..Loop to a Do .. Loop Until().

**Refactoring**

```
Public Sub Sort(collectionObject As Collection)

    If IsNull(collectionObject) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim item As Variant
    Dim innerItem As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim index As Long

    Dim hasSwapped As Boolean
    Dim collectionCount As Long

    collectionCount = collectionObject.Count

    Do

        hasSwapped = False

        For i = 1 To collectionCount
            index = i

            If IsObject(collectionObject(i)) Then
                Set item = collectionObject(i)
            Else
                item = collectionObject(i)
            End If

            For j = i + 1 To collectionCount
                If IsObject(collectionObject(j)) Then
                    Set innerItem = collectionObject(j)
                Else
                    innerItem = collectionObject(j)
                End If

                If item > innerItem Then
                    collectionObject.Add item, After:=j
                    collectionObject.Remove index
                    index = j
                    hasSwapped = True
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

    Loop Until Not hasSwapped

End Sub
```